# Something wrong with this .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my current htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^register/ index.php?view=register [L]

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/[0-9a-z\-]*/$ index.php?view=news&id=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^movie/([0-9]+)/[0-9a-z\-]*/$ index.php?view=movies&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^actor/([0-9]+)/[0-9a-z\-]*/$ index.php?view=actor&id=$1&name=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^country/([0-9]+)/[0-9a-z\-]*/$ index.php?view=country&id=$1&name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^country/([0-9]+)/[0-9a-z\-]/[0-9]*/$ index.php view=country&id=$1&name=$2$country=$3 [L]
```

the problem is if I visit domain.com/country/3/usa/1/ it cant find the attr "country"

I have tried doing

> echo $_GET['country'];

but it only returns a unidentified variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a bad practice to implement routing via .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last entry is missing a question mark:

```
RewriteRule ^country/([0-9]+)/[0-9a-z\-]/[0-9]*/$ index.php?view=country&id=$1&name=$2&country=$3 [L]
```

Comment: if i do echo $_GET['country']; it now returns nothing, not even a error :$

Comment: var_dump/print_r $_GET and make sure everything is getting passed in. I edited the answer because you had  `&name=$2$country=$3` instead of `&name=$2&country=$3`, which meant that $_GET['country'] did not exist.